# Show elements of m2m based on template in a template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a simple (relatively) model such as:

models.py

```
class Author( models.Model ):
    first_name = model.CharField( max_length=30 );
    last_name = model.CharField( max_length=30 );
    something = model.FloatField( );

class Book( models.Model ):
    name = model.CharField( max_length=200 );
    authors = model.ManyToManyField( Author );
```

template/book.html

```
{% for book in books %}
    {{ book.name }}

    <div id="authors">
    {% for author in book.authors.all %}

        {{ author|template:"author_short.html" }}  *** unsure here

    {% endfor %}
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

author_short.html (for example...)

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #f00;">
    Name: {{ first_name }} {{ last_name }} 
</div>
```

What I would like to be able to do is to format the authors' information in the inner loop based on some template. It seems like I should be able to do that type of thing.

In the end what I want to do is to be able to add an author (in the same format!) using an ajax call.  I know I can add via ajax, but I would have to have the formatting definition in two places, and therefore not that DRY (unless I am missing another way of doing this, which is quite possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`include` templatetag for this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include).

> Loads a template and renders it with the current context. This is a way of “including” other templates within a template

```
{% for author in book.authors.all %}

    {% include "author_short.html" %}

{% endfor %}
```

and `author_short.html` can still be:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #f00;">
    Name: {{ first_name }} {{ last_name }} 
</div>
```

which can be reused

Comment: D'oh, that was easy. Seriously... wow. not sure how I missed that.